# best way to convert database table in codefirst to model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

i have table of news , and i need convert to model .

like this :

i need pass to view `NewsModel` and i have table `News` .

i convert that :

```
 public ActionResult EditNews(int NewsID)
    {
        NewsModel model = new NewsModel();
        var editservice = _NewsSerivce.NewsByID(NewsID);
        model.NewsID = editservice.NewsID;
        model.NewsHeader = editservice.NewsHeader;
        model.NewsTitle = editservice.NewsTitle;
        model.NewsText = editservice.NewsText;
        model.NewsDefaultFile = editservice.NewsDefaultFile;
        model.CatID = editservice.CatID;
        model.SubCatID = editservice.SubCatID;
        DropDownCategory(model);
        return View("Edit",model);
    }
```

it work but i need use best way for convert .

what best way ?

Comment: Try Entity Framework with "Code First from database": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this nuget:
http://automapper.org/

Documentation is here:
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started

I dont know how your class looks so i make my class:

```
  public  class TestClass
{
    public int NewsID { get; set; }
    public string NewsHeader { get; set; }
    public string NewsTitle { get; set; }
    public string NewsText { get; set; }
    public string NewsDefaultFile { get; set; }
    public int CatID { get; set; }
    public int SubCatID { get; set; }
}
```

and my mapping class:

```
   public class NewTestClass
{
    public int NewsID { get; set; }
    public string NewsHeader { get; set; }
    public string NewsTitle { get; set; }
    public string NewsText { get; set; }
    public string NewsDefaultFile { get; set; }
    public int CatID { get; set; }
    public int SubCatID { get; set; }
}
```

i have map this class like this:

```
 TestClass tc = new TestClass { CatID = 1, NewsID = 1, SubCatID = 1, NewsDefaultFile = "test1", NewsHeader = "test2", NewsText = "test3", NewsTitle = "test4" };

        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<TestClass, NewTestClass>());
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<TestClass, NewTestClass>());

        var mapper = new Mapper(config);

        NewTestClass ntx = Mapper.Map<NewTestClass>(tc);

        Console.WriteLine(ntx.NewsID);
```

Comment: can you map this for me ?

Comment: Now i can't:( i'm in work to 5 pm  o'clock :( Edit: do the same like on this video http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=155

Comment: It does not take too long for you :))))

Comment: man , i have new problem with automaper . i ask question in this post or other ???

Comment: Meaby in other with tag #automapper. If i have free time i try help

Answer (score -1):

in my viewpoint, this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620(v=vs.113).aspx) is the best of the method to Entity Framework Code First to an Existing Database.

In the visual studio go to Project -> Add New Item…
Select Data from the left menu and then ADO.NET Entity Data Model,
Enter BloggingContext as the name and click OK
This launches the Entity Data Model Wizard
Select Code First from Database and click Next
WizardOneCFE
Select the connection to the database you created in the first section and click Next
WizardTwoCFE
Click the checkbox next to Tables to import all tables and click Finish
WizardThreeCFE